# Is Scrapy's asynchronicity what is hindering my CSV results file from being created straightforwardly?

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler, scrapy

My scrapy project "drills down" from list pages, retrieving data for the listed items at varying levels up to several deep.  There could be many pages of listed items with handfuls of different items/links on each page. I'm collecting details (and storing them in a single CSV Excel file) of each of the items from: the page it is listed on, the page link in that list ("more details" page), and yet another page - the original listing by the item's manufacturer, let's say.

Because I am building a CSV file, it would be VERY helpful to put each item's data on a single line before my parse process moves along to the next item.  I could do it nicely if only I could get a Request to launch when I demand it while I am writing the CSV line for that item on the list page it appears on.  I would just "drill down" as many levels as I need with a different parse function for each level, if needed, staying with a single item all the way until I have the entire CSV file line that it will need.

Instead of it being that easy, it appears that I am going to have to re-write the CSV file for EVERY ITEM at EVERY LEVEL because I can't get scrapy to give me the items' "more details" links responses until I've exited the entire parse function of the page of items listing, thus the end of my CSV file is no longer at the item being processed, and I'm having to have a unique field on each line to look each item up at each level, re-write the file, etc.

Understand, I can't know which callback level will be the last one for any particular item.  That is determined on an item-by-item basis.  Some items won't even have "deeper" levels.  My only idea left is to have only a single recursive callback function that handles all callback levels, but is that way this kind of thing is done by the rest of you, or does scrapy have some means of "Request and wait for response" or something similar?   I'm not wanting to install a sql database on my laptop, never having set one up before.

Thank you!!!

```py
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import csv
from meow.items import meowItem, meowPage
from scrapy.http import Request
import os
from mmap import mmap

class meowlistpage(Spider):
    name="melist"
    prefixhref='http://www.meow.com'
    #add '2_p/', '3_p/', or '4_p/', etc. to get to meow's other pages
    start_urls = [prefixhref+"/homes/for_sale/CO/house,mobile,land_type/10_rid/3000-30000_price/11-117_mp/800000-8000000_lot/lot_sort/46.377254,-96.82251,30.845647,-114.312744_rect/5_zm/1_p/1_rs/"]
    print 'Retrieving first page...'
    def parse(self, response):
        print 'First page retrieved'
        name="melist";prefixhref='http://www.meow.com';
        csvfilename = 'C:\\Python27\\My scripts\\meow\\'+name+'.csv';csvfile = open(csvfilename, 'w');pass;csvfile.close()
        hxs = Selector(response)
        page_tags=hxs.xpath("//div[@id='search-results']/article")
        for page_tags in page_tags:
            item = meowItem()
            item['ad_link']=prefixhref+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@href").extract())[3:-2]
            idendplace=str(item['ad_link']).index('_zpid')-12; backhashstr=str(item['ad_link'])[idendplace:]; 
            idstartplace=backhashstr.index('/')+1; idendplace=len(backhashstr)-backhashstr.index('_zpid');
            item['zpid']=str(backhashstr)[idstartplace:-idendplace]
            item['sale_sold']=str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[1]/@class").extract())[8:-17]#"recentlySold" or "forSale"
            item['prop_price']=str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[2]/strong/text()").extract())[3:-2]
            if (str(item['sale_sold'])=='recentlySold'):item['prop_price']=str(item['prop_price'])+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[1]/strong/text()").extract())[3:-2]
            try:
                dollrsgn=item['prop_price'].index('$');item['prop_price']=str(item['prop_price'])[dollrsgn:]
            except:pass
            item['ad_title']=str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@title").extract())[3:-2]
            prop_latitude1=page_tags.xpath("@latitude").extract();item['prop_latitude']=str(prop_latitude1)[3:-8]+'.'+str(prop_latitude1)[5:-2]
            prop_longitude1=page_tags.xpath("@longitude").extract();item['prop_longitude']=str(prop_longitude1)[3:-8]+'.'+str(prop_longitude1)[7:-2]
            item['prop_address']=str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[1]/text()").extract())[3:-2]+', '+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]+', '+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[3]/text()").extract())[3:-2]+'  '+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[4]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
            mightmentionacres = str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]+' | '+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]+' | '+str(page_tags.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@title").extract())[3:-2]+' | '#+str()[3:-2]#this last segment comes from full ad
            item['prop_acres'] = mightmentionacres

            #Here is where I'm talking about

            yield Request(str(item['ad_link']), meta={'csvfilename':csvfilename, 'item':item}, dont_filter=True, callback = self.getthispage)

            #By this point, I wanted all the callback[s] to have had executed, but they don't - Scrapy waits to launch them until after this function completes

            csvfile = open(csvfilename, 'ab')
            outwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            outwriter.writerow(item['zpid'], [item['sale_sold'], item['prop_price'], item['ad_title'],
                                             item['prop_address'], item['prop_latitude'],
                                              item['prop_longitude'], item['prop_acres'],
                                               item['ad_link'], item['parcelnum'], item['lot_width']])
            csvfile.close()
        #retrieve href of next page of ads
        next_results_pg=1
        page_tags=hxs.xpath("//div[@id='list-container']/div[@id='search-pagination-wrapper-2']/ul[1]")
        while (str(page_tags.xpath(".//li["+str(next_results_pg)+"]/@class").extract())[3:-2]!='current'):
            next_results_pg+=1;
            if (next_results_pg>80):
                break
        next_results_pg+=1#;item['next_results_pg'] = next_results_pg
        if (str(page_tags.xpath(".//li["+str(next_results_pg)+"]/@class").extract())[3:-2]=='next'):return
        next_results_pg_href = prefixhref+str(page_tags.xpath(".//li["+str(next_results_pg)+"]/a/@href").extract())[3:-2]#
        if (next_results_pg_href != prefixhref):#need to also avoid launching pages otherwise not desired
            page = meowPage()
            page['next_results_pg_href'] = next_results_pg_href
            print 'Retrieving page '+ next_results_pg_href
#           yield Request(next_results_pg_href, dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse)
        return
#       if (item['next_results_pg_href']==prefixhref):
#           print 'No results pages found after this one, next+results_pg='+str(next_results_pg)
#       else:
#           print 'Next page to parse after this one is '+str(item['next_results_pg_href'])

    def getthispage(self, response): 
        #Even though the yield statement was used, 
        #nothing here really gets executed until
        #until the first parse function resumes and 
        #then finishes completely.
        return
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Scrapy CSV exporter writes serialized items in a file. If your item needs multiple requests to complete, you can pass the incomplete item in a Request's meta dict and return the finished item in the callback that adds the final bits of info. Could you share some spider code you are using so we can advise better?

Comment: I will try that as well as another idea or two I got.  Lets consider this answered.  
Thank you paul t.

Comment: The meta dict idea fails, and here's why: the "yield Request(url,..." allows program execution to return too early.  That is, the statements that follow the yield statement get executed before the callback function is ever able to process the request's response.  Just rewording my original question, actually.  I do realize that I could write all the filled-in

Comment: I got cut off somehow.  Anyway, I could do this the long way and write the data items to temp files as I find them, then concatenate the files after removing unwanted cr/lf at the ends of files, and all that.  I'm just wanting to get around installing a sql database on my laptop, not ever having set one up before.  So I'm still struggling with this.  I didn't want to post code b/c of the site names and all the trouble it would take to remove them, but I'll work on doing it now.

Comment: you got the `meta` idea wrong, using it you dont yield an item, you add some values to the request that will appear in the response as well, `meta` is the right way to go in your case

Comment: Thank you, Guy.  I'm working on that right now!

Comment: Think of it this way: yield spawns a one-way daemon in scrapy. Data collected by it never makes it back up to the process where the yield was executed...the daemon does its thing and dies, even though it may end with a return. Its thing had better include storing the data someplace global before it dies. Like a file  or files or a sql database. The sql database idea limits portability, even though it is more conventional. The file storage idea is in-elegant, especially when multiple, simultaneous daemon are sent out, as when there are multiple links to traverse for a single item from one page

Comment: I'll resort to using sqlite3 that come with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution using the standard SQLite3 that is packaged with Python 2.7:

```
#  items.py contents:
#from scrapy.item import Item, Field

#class TrackItemScrapeItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
#    f_1 = Field()
#    f_2 = Field()
#    sale_sold = Field()
#    price = Field()
#    item_ad_link = Field()
#    .and so on
#    .
#    .
#    .
#    <EOF>

#  TrackItemScrapespider.py contents:
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
import csv
import sys
from zillow.items import TrackItemScrapeItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import os
import sqlite3 #allows scrapy asynchronous processes a global storage place for each item's scraped info
import time

class TrackItemScraper(Spider):
    name="buyitemslist"
    start_urls = ['http://www.buythisandthat.com']
    tablecolumns=""
    prikeyfldname='f_1'
    for field in getattr(TrackItemScrapeItem, 'fields'):
        # Just realize the order of these fields in the database has no relation to the order in items.py
        # nor is it consistent each time
        if (field==prikeyfldname):
            tablecolumns+=str(field)+' TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, '
        else:
            tablecolumns+=str(field)+' TEXT, '
    tablecolumns=tablecolumns[:-2]
    con=None
    con=sqlite3.connect(name+".db");tablename='CrawlResults'
    if (con==None):
        print "SQL database not getting opened by sqlite3 !  (Is there room for the file ?)";sys.exit(1)
    cur=con.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute('select * from '+tablename)
        cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info('+tablename+')')
        data = cur.fetchall()
        for d in data:
            print d[0], d[1], d[2]
        cur.execute('select * from '+tablename)
        print '\n'+str(cur.fetchall())
    except:
        cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+tablename);cur.execute('CREATE TABLE '+tablename+' ('+tablecolumns+')')
    if (raw_input('\n\n Do you want to delete the previous '+name+'.CSV file?').capitalize()=='Y'):
        csvfile=name+'.csv'
        with open(csvfile, 'w') as csv_file:
            csv_file.close()
    if (raw_input('\n\n Do you want to save the results from the previous run to a new '+name+'.CSV file?').capitalize()=='Y'):
        csvfile=name+'.csv'
        with open(csvfile, 'w') as csv_file:
            csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
            cur.execute('select * from '+tablename)
            csv_writer.writerows(cur)
            csv_file.close()
    if (raw_input('\n\n Do you want to clear out previous results from memory now to start clean?  Answer no ONLY if you haven\'t added new fields!').capitalize()=='Y'):
        cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '+tablename);cur.execute('CREATE TABLE '+tablename+' ('+tablecolumns+')')
    instancesrunning=1#start at 1 because a yield is about to happen implicitly for an asynchronous instance
#    seccntdwn=25#for failsafe counter, can used with next-to-last (for example) parse instance to tolerate an instance collision decrementing instancesrunning counter

    def parse(self, response):#recursive but first entry won't have meta args
        try:
            pageschema = response.meta['pageschema']
        except:#entered function without meta args, pageschema 0
            pageschema = 0
        hxs = Selector(response)
        if (pageschema==0):#top level pages
            ad_list=hxs.xpath("//xpath_to_ad_list")
        #    page_tags=''

            for item_ad in ad_list:
                item = TrackItemScrapeItem()
                # parse code for prikeyfldname field must be in here instead of these comment lines
                #item[prikeyfldname]=item_ad.xpath(".//div[whatever...
                # for this example, item['sale_sold'] and item['price'] will need parsing code in here as well
                con=None
                con=sqlite3.connect(self.name+".db")
                with sqlite3.connect(self.name+".db") as con:
                    cur=con.cursor()
                    replacevar = False
                    try:
                        cmd='INSERT INTO ' +str(self.tablename)+ ' (' +str(self.prikeyfldname)+ ') VALUES (\'' +str(item[self.prikeyfldname])+ '\')'
                        cur.execute(cmd)
                        print str(cmd) #won't see this unless insert succeeded 
                        con.commit()
                        #replacevar is for any fields for this item that you might want to keep old contents of, appending current info only when this item was not new in this run
                        replacevar = True
                        self.storthis(str(item[self.prikeyfldname]), 'sale_sold', str(item['sale_sold']), replace=replacevar)
                    except:#option example: if wanting to save old price, moves it into sale_sold if sale_sold field has changed
                        cmd='UPDATE ' +self.tablename+ ' SET sale_sold = \''  +str(item['sale_sold'])+ ', last retrieved advertised price was \' || (SELECT price) WHERE ' +str(self.prikeyfldname)+ ' = ' +str(item[self.prikeyfldname])+ ' AND sale_sold <> \'' +str(item['sale_sold'])+ '\''
                        print str(cmd)#prints even if SQL update fails for troubleshooting
                        cur.execute(cmd)
                        con.commit()
                #now storthis code for price field because we already parsed it
                self.storthis( str(item[self.prikeyfldname]),'price',item['price'], replace=True)
                #
                #remainder of parses and stores in here for this item, saving the ad_link for next yield/Request
                #
                self.instancesrunning+=1    
                yield Request(str(item['ad_link']), meta={'item':item, 'pageschema':1}, dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse)
            #code in here to determine link for next page of list of ads
            if (final_page_of_list_is_complete):
                self.savetofileiflastinstance()#the way to exit all callback instances
                return
            #parse link to next page in here if not done already
            time.sleep(6)#being nice to host
            self.instancesrunning+=1
            yield Request(next_results_pg_href, dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse)#don't need meta for list pages
        elif (pageschema==1): #we are to parse using 2nd schema
            item = response.meta['item']
            page_tags=hxs.xpath("//as you need for this schema"
            #parse and store in here, just remember in this example that we didn't pass along in meta whether this item is new or not this run
            for (every link on this page needing scraped but adjust pageschema for each type):
                self.instancesrunning+=1    
                yield Request(str(item['ad_link']), meta={'item':item, 'pageschema':as_needed}, dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse)
        elif (pageschema==2): #same general code in here as for schema 1
        elif (pageschema==3): #same general code in here as for schema 1
        elif (pageschema==4): #same general code in here as for schema 1
        self.savetofileiflastinstance()
        return

    def storthis (self, uniquefieldvalue, storfieldname, storfieldvalue, replace):
#       check for nulls etc in here, if desired  
        con=None
        con=sqlite3.connect(self.name+".db")
        if (replace==False):
            cmd='UPDATE '+str(self.tablename)+' SET '+storfieldname+' = (SELECT '+storfieldname+') || \''+storfieldvalue+'\' WHERE '+self.prikeyfldname+'=\''+uniquefieldvalue+'\''
        else:
            cmd='UPDATE '+str(self.tablename)+' SET '+storfieldname+'=\''+storfieldvalue+'\' where '+self.prikeyfldname+'=\''+uniquefieldvalue+'\''
        print str(cmd)
        try:
            with con:
                cur=con.cursor()
                cur.execute(cmd)
                con.commit()
        except:pass##we don't want to return with an error unexcepted
        return 

    def savetofileiflastinstance(self):
#        instancesrunningpre=self.instancesrunning #if utilizing the failsafe instance counting
        self.instancesrunning-=1
        if (self.instancesrunning>0):pass #or failsafe counter code in here
#            #if concerned that this might still be the last if an instance collision ever occurred while decrementing self.instancesrunning
#             we'll wait seccntdwn seconds for another instance to have its presence indicated by a change in the counter
#            if ():
                self.savetofileiflastinstance()
        else:   #this was last instance, write the csv file
            con=None
            con=sqlite3.connect(self.name+".db")
            cur=con.cursor()
            csvfile=self.name+'.csv'
            with open(csvfile, 'a') as csv_file:
                cur.execute('select * from '+self.tablename)
                csv_writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
                csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in cur.description])
                csv_writer.writerows(cur)
                csv_file.close()
            print '\n\nWrote the results to the '+self.name+'.CSV file.  Make sure this is the LAST line of output from this sript!  If it isn\'t, rewrite the source coding for instance tracking.\n\n'
            con.commit()
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged your spider code a bit to make the "item in meta" a bit clearer (I hope)

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from meow.items import meowItem, meowPage
from scrapy.http import Request
import urlparse
import pprint

class meowlistpage(Spider):
    name="melist"
    allowed_domains = ['meow.com']

    start_urls = ['http://www.meow.com'
                  '/homes/for_sale/CO'
                  '/10_rid/42.382894,-101.931152,35.496456,-109.171143_rect/6_zm/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('First page retrieved')
        selector = Selector(response)

        # loop over the subroutine results, yielding each;
        # could be an Item or a Request
        for result in self.parse_page_articles(response, selector):
            yield result

        # look for next pages (except the one marked as "current")
        for next_page in selector.xpath("""
                //div[@id="search-pagination-wrapper-2"]
                    /ul/li[not(@class="current")]/a/@href""").extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, next_page))

    def getthispage(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta["item"]
        # self.log("in %s (getthispage:\nitem to complete \n%r" % (
        #    response.url, pprint.pformat(item)))
        #
        # continue extracting data from this page and store it in item
        # item["some_other_field"] = "info that was missing in listing page"
        # and when done, do:
        yield item

    def parse_page_articles(self, response, selector):
        page_tags = selector.xpath("//div[@id='search-results']/article")
        for article in page_tags:
            item = meowItem()
            item['ad_link'] = urlparse.urljoin(response.url,
                article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@href").extract()[0]).encode('utf-8')

            idendplace = item['ad_link'].index('_zpid')-12
            backhashstr = item['ad_link'][idendplace:]
            idstartplace = backhashstr.index('/') + 1
            idendplace = len(backhashstr)-backhashstr.index('_zpid')

            item['zpid'] = backhashstr[idstartplace:-idendplace]
            item['sale_sold'] = article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[1]/@class").extract()[0][8:-17]#"recentlySold" or "forSale"
            item['prop_price'] = article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[2]/strong/text()").extract()[0][3:-2]
            if (item['sale_sold'] == 'recentlySold'):
                item['prop_price'] = item['prop_price'] + article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[1]/dt[1]/strong/text()").extract()[0][3:-2]
            try:
                dollrsgn = item['prop_price'].index('$')
                item['prop_price'] = item['prop_price'][dollrsgn:]
            except:
                pass

            item['ad_title'] = article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@title").extract()[0][3:-2]

            prop_latitude1 = article.xpath("@latitude").extract()
            item['prop_latitude'] = (str(prop_latitude1)[3:-8]
                + '.' + str(prop_latitude1)[5:-2])
            prop_longitude1 = article.xpath("@longitude").extract()
            item['prop_longitude'] = (
                str(prop_longitude1)[3:-8]
                + '.' + str(prop_longitude1)[7:-2])

            item['prop_address'] = (
                str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[1]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
                + ', ' + str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
                + ', ' + str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[3]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
                + '  ' + str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/span[4]/text()").extract())[3:-2])

            mightmentionacres = (
                str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
                +' | '
                +str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[2]/text()").extract())[3:-2]
                +' | '
                +str(article.xpath(".//div[1]/dl[2]/dt[1]/span[1]/span[1]/a/@title").extract())[3:-2]
                +' | '
                #+str()[3:-2]#this last segment comes from full ad
                )
            item['prop_acres'] = mightmentionacres

            yield Request(item['ad_link'], meta={'item':item},
                dont_filter=True, callback = self.getthispage)
```

Invoking your spider with `scrapy crawl melist -o melist_items.csv -t csv` should give you your items in CSV format

Comment: Great answer, Paul, I'm sure, though I already have sqlite3 going now. Using sqlite3 with a unique id field for each item works to give me a global place to store item details, one item per db table line, no matter which parse callback level they are retrieved from or how many items have already been added to the table. If I find the sqlite3 way doesn't work in the end for some unforeseen reason, you can bet I'll be coming back to your way! and thank you Guy as well!

Comment: I simply wanted to show a more scrapy-idiomatic way of doing what you're after. But whatever works for you is fine :)

Comment: Paul, my SQLite3 quit on me (stopped taking INSERT commands, gives 'Operational Error' now for INSERT commands), so while I troubleshoot it, a question for you: I looked at what your code is doing, beautiful job, too. But I'm not seeing how it takes into account that it needs to collect data on an/each item down to several levels of pages, sometimes multiple links on a page, for some items some pages won't be there. Regardless the order the bits of data come from scrapy, they need to get attached w/the item of 1st pg. My code just wasn't to that point yet for you to see where I needed to go.

Comment: (  Found my SQLite3 problem: a fetchall() deselects what got selected for it.  I'm new at SQL...& scrapy, of course)

Comment: SQLite3 did the job for me.  It is amazing how out-of-sequence scrapy retrieves its pages that only a sql fix could deal with.  Now I find the scrapy Selector can't deal with web pages that I'm trying to scrape. They are invisible past a certain point.  I'm wondering if parslepy would fix that problem.   You would know, Paul.  [sigh...]

Comment: My selector problem is addressed here, thanks to Rho:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433961/scrapy-hxs-select-not-selecting-all-results

Comment: "It is amazing how out-of-sequence scrapy retrieves its pages": By default, Scrapy retrieves the pages in [depth-first order](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-crawl-in-breadth-first-or-depth-first-order). You can change that to breadth-first order if you want. I wouldn't say the SQL fix is the only solution, or that there is a problem to fix in the first place. Scrapy has an asynchronous model for writing code with callbacks that is based on Twisted. Trying to do synchronous programming with Scrapy is difficult because it's not meant for that.

Comment: Right, Paul.  It just catches most newcomers off-guard if they're trying to keep their items separate when several callbacks are returning data at once on different items.  Its certainly not a failure, just a characteristic. But I've watched the results come back a handful of times now and have not seen them come IN in a consistent order, whether breadth first or not, though I'll buy the notion that the web page requests get sent OUT in some consistent order or another. And I am impressed with how solidly the sql solution does the job, though I would call it more brute force than elegant